# Wordpress sidebar positioning on page and post

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, sidebar

for a few hours now I'm trying to solve a problem I encounter with the standard sidebar on my localy hosted wordpress site.

The code of my sidebar is the following:
CSS in the Customizer:

```js
function mySlide(){
var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
var y = document.getElementById("slider");
if(x.style.right === "0px"){
 x.style.right = "-305px"; 
 y.src = "arrow_left.png";
}else{
 x.style.right = "0px";
 y.src= "arrow_right.png";
 }
}
```

```css
#sidebar{ 
 background-color: #571e0b;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50px;
 right: -305px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transform: 0.5s;
 z-index: 2;
}
#slider {
 padding: 10px;;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 left: -65px; 
 background-color: #571e0b;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <input alt="slider_button" id="slider" type="image" onclick="mySlide()" src="arrow_left.png">
</div>
```

This kind of sidebar is positioned on posts and pages. However, the difference between the right attribute of #sidebar on pages and on post is 75px and I can't find a reason to.

The only clue I could find so far is, that it has something to do with pages being fullwidth and blogs being not.

Other characteristics of my website:
Theme: Themify Ultra v1.99
Plugins: Contact Form 7, Themify Portfolio Post, WP Super Cache

What i tried so far:
deleting everything on the affected pages.
reinstalling the theme and plugins

Would marry someone for a solution...

Kind regards

Comment: Here isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: Could you please tell me what additional informations you need?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution i found is a workaround with CSS. I set all pages to being not full width, and afterwards I used CSS to tell the container to resize.

It's as simple as:

```
#content{
  width: 80%;    
}
```